# AWS multiple sites, one instance, multiple ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have one Wordpress on Apache already deployed on port 80 and configured through Route 53. This is obviously on port 80. Now, I have created a new project in react.js that is listening to different port, port 3000. Both sites are on the same EC2 Ubuntu instance. I would like to attach to the second site (node.js) different domain name and configure this to work, however, I don't know how to do it. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Point the two domains to your EC2 elastic IP(A records).

On apache, configure virtual host which enable you to run two web site on a single machine. see this link: [Apache Virtual Host documentation - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)